# What does an equals sign mean inside the angle braces of a type parameter

Tags: typescript

In the type definitions for Bluebird promises, there is a catch function that is defined as such:

```js
catch<U = R>(onReject: ((error: any) => Resolvable<U>) | undefined | null): Bluebird<U | R>;
```

The type "R" comes from the Bluebird class declaration itself, whereas "U" is the symbol used as the first type parameter for all of Bluebird's functions.

what does `<U = R>` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default value for the generic parameter.

Surprisingly it's not anywhere in the official documentation, hence only a link to the github issue.

References:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175

Comment: So if a user doesn't set a <U> type when calling Catch, it will default to what was defined for Bluebird?

Comment: It is (now?) in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-parameter-defaults). Though I am as clueless as TypeScript, what that "Container" is supposed to be.